# Change color of back button in the page header

Tags: css, sapui5

I want to change color (e.g. to red) of back button in the page header, please look in the picture:

[image]

When I used the css bellow:

```
.sapUiIcon:before {
    color: red;
}
```

It works but it changed all sapUiIcons as:

[image]

I would like to change just back button color but in the all app pages, so it can be applied globally for all back buttons. Probably there will be solution for approaching specific back button in the specific page header and apply css style, but I would prefer global solution, one css class for all pages if it is possible. Thanks for any hint.

EDITED 13:15 160517 (added back button element):

[image]

EDITED 14:07 160517 added woring [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/5GUqwk0RQrbko6DE8UbV?p=preview), please try the css styling in the test.css file.

Comment: Please post some code of your header

Comment: do more spesific selector? like `header .sapUiIcon::before{}`

Comment: have u try !important ?

Comment: try `.sapMBtnIconLeft:before {color: red !important;}`

Comment: Provide relevant html code snippet as well.

Comment: Ismail I did. Yudi it does not do anything. Jonas all icons are red. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add (nav-color) class to the desired page and extend the selector.

```
.nav-color button[title="Back"] .sapUiIcon:before{
  color: red!important;
 }



var oPage = new sap.m.Page({
    title : "Page title: ChartContainer",
    enableScrolling : false,
    showNavButton: true,
    content : [fixFlex]
});

oPage.addStyleClass("nav-color");
```

Comment: Thanks Santhosh, but still all icons are red.

Comment: <Page title="MULTI PAGE" class="nav-color" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onNavBack">
 </Page> I assume you did like this

Comment: No I did not :) But now I did here plnkr.co/edit/4qmHs55IgcvM5lOxlsBY?p=preview and nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you @Santhosh this is what I was looking for. Here is working demo https://plnkr.co/edit/WtJDH3UvVI14FUDfPk3T?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshots, I would try using below:

```
.sapMBtnIconLeft.sapUiIcon::before { color: red }
```

I guess HTML class ".sapMBtnIconLeft" indicates arrow left icon, so using together with ".sapUiIcon" will increase specificity a little bit ;-)

Comment: Thanks Achwilko, but still all icons are red.

Answer (score 0):

Per SAP standards, do not override control class styling.
See [Developer Guide](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/9d87f925dfbb4e99b9e2963693aa00ef.html)

If you want a red nav-back button on your page, try using `sap.m.Bar`.

```
<Page showHeader="false">
    <Bar design="Header">
        <contentLeft>
            <core:Icon src="sap-icon://nav-back" color="red" press="onNavBack"/>
        </contentLeft>
        <contentMiddle>
            <Title text="Page Title"/>
        </contentMiddle>
    </Bar>
    <content>

    </content>
</Page>
```

This isn't a global solution like you've requested, but the best solution to stay within SAP standards.